# Pass Props From navBar Button Using React-Native-Router-Flux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-router-flux

I have a fairly fleshed out project using `react-native-router-flux` and I'm trying to pass an object through `props`. Normally I could call `Actions.someKey({ someProp: object })` for the navigation, but I'm trying to navigate using the `rightButtonImage` where it doesn't have access to the component's `props`.

For instance:

**`Router.js`**

```
<Router>
  <Scene1
    rightButtonImage={someImage}
    onRight={() => Actions.sceneTwo()}
  />
  <Scene2 key="sceneTwo" />
</Router>
```

I want to pass an object that Scene1's component has access to, when I move to Scene2.

Comment: Do you want to sent do `Scene2` the `someImage` value?

Comment: No Scene1's component has an object as a prop that I need to pass to Scene2.

Comment: You could store it and pass it as its own `prop` within the `Actions.sceneTwo()`

Comment: The problem is the object is dynamic not static, so I have say Scene1, Scene2, Scene3. Scene1 has a list made up of fetched data. When an item is selected it moves to Scene2 with relevant props of the listitem. I want to carry forth the object to Scene3 from the navBar button. If the Action.Scene3() was being triggered in Scene2's component, I could just attach ({ prop: value )} to it, but I'm triggering the Actions.Scene3() in the Router component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be helpful for you:
In each component i.e in componentDidMount you can do something like that:

```
Actions.refresh({
 rightTitle: "Next",
 rightButtonTextStyle: {color: 'red'},
 onRight: this.goSomewhere, 
 rightButtonImage: someImage
})
```